# June Data Dump Extraction Problems

Tags: support, status-norepro, data-dump

I downloaded the [June Data Dump](http://www.clearbits.net/torrents/1794-jun-2011) from ClearBits, and I'm having trouble extracting the Stack Overflow files. First, when I extract the `stackoverflow.com.7z.001` file, it just creates another [7-Zip](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/7-Zip) file named `stackoverflow.com.7z`. I can't open that file in 7-Zip directly, but if I click on extract to folder, it will create another `stackoverflow.com.7z` file in the folder I selected.  This file will not extract further and gives the error "Cannot open file c:.... as archive".  I didn't see any mention of the new dump on [which I thought was weird](https://blog.stackoverflow.com/category/cc-wiki-dump/)>, but I got the ClearBits update in my RSS reader so I figured I would download anyway.  I am using 7-Zip 9.2 on Windows XP 32-bit.

**Update 1:**

Also, I just tried opening "serverfault.com.7z" and it stated "Cannot open C:...\serverfault.com.7z" as archive.

**Update 2:**

I also did a "Force Recheck" in [µTorrent](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/%CE%9CTorrent), and it reported no problems.

Answer (score 1):

I just extracted the 7z archive for Stack Overflow on the source machine where the 7z was created - no errors.

I also was able to open the serverfault.com.7z archive:

[image: serverfault dump]

I'm currently downloading the dump to my home machine and will test to see if it's an issue with the torrent package, but I know the archives are fine at the source.

**Update 1:**

I downloaded the June Data Dump and was able to extract Stack Overflow on my home theater PC without any issues:

[image: StackOverflow dump]

I can only suggest downloading the dump again and see if there were any issues during the transfer.

Comment: For serverfault.com.7z I got an MD5 Checksum of DC5BFA7A970A6D33774AFFCADD1A6F25 Can you verify if this is correct or not.  I'll try redownloading later.  Although I'm not sure why that would help, bittorrent is supposed to have checksumming built in.  Also, none of the files I tried could be extracted.

Comment: Never mind.  Just checked my files in a hex editor.  They're all zeroed out. Maybe there's something wrong with my bittorrent client.

Comment: Very strange re: your bittorrent client - the MD5 Checksum for serverfault.com.7z is 492733afec5e7ac5c0c8b6135a7e8003

Comment: Started download again.  First few files have come in ok.  Not sure what happened the first time around.